# How to configure Apache to require basic auth AND respect directory and file restrictions?

Tags: apache-2.4

Consider this configuration excerpt from an Apache 2.4.6 (CentOS) setup:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.(.*)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   <Location /admin>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
      AuthUserFile /some/path/to/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
   </Location>
   <Directory /var/www/admin/uploads>
      <Files *.php>
         Require all denied
      </Files>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Dot and .php files are accessible under `/admin` providing authentication has succeeded. If `/admin` is not an actual directory (and we can't use a `<Directory>` block), how can this be configured to respect the dot and php file restrictions?

I have read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html and understand the order in which the configurations apply:

> 1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and .htaccess done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
> 2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory "~">`)
> 3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
> 4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
> 5. `<If>`

So `<Location>` is overriding `<Directory>` and `<FilesMatch>`, presumably the `Require valid-user` is negating the effects of `Require all denied`? If so, how can we say in the `<Location>` match require a valid user and respect the other conditions?